# How to do Google signIn integration in react native without firebase (in Android)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-signin

Here I'm just start learning react native(latest version). I almost cover all the basic in react-native, Now I want to use Google Authentication in my app without firebase. I read almost every documents which is present on google but still not able to find how to do this or may be I'm not able to get these documents correctly.

Here Is anyone who guide me how to Google Authentication in React Native in simple way?

Answer (score 2):

i am not an expert react native developer but i have some experience doing React.js. I faced the same problem and the solution below helped me :

https://dev.to/suyashvash/google-authsignin-in-react-native-without-firebase-43n

Give it a try it may help :)

Comment: Hey, I followed the same step from this document, and I'm getting this error -- "keytool -list -v -keystore app/my_release_key.keystore -alias my_key_alias
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: app/my_release_key.keystore
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: app/my_release_key.keystore"

Comment: After run this command in android/app----- "keytool -list -v -keystore app/my_release_key.keystore -alias my_key_alias"

Comment: I think you need to specify the path to the keystore file, the given path in the command you r running is not the right one.

Comment: A note for Expo users: when I ran an `expo-dev-client` build, I needed the SHA from "Credentials/[Application Identifier]/SHA-1 Certificate Fingerprint" in the Expo web UI. I presume once uploaded to the app store and if you're using "Signing by Google Play" then it'll be the value from "Setup/App signing/SHA-1 certificate fingerprint" in the Play Console (I haven't got that far yet!)

Answer (score 0):

When running the app in your Android emulator and if you're using Expo, you need to ensure that you have the Android client ID for the debug key in the Google console.

So, you need to create a client ID with the debug key SHA1 (`<your-project>/android/app/debug.keystore`). You can get it if you run this in your android project

`./gradlew signingReport`

variant: debug
config: debug
alias: androiddebugkey

It will get you the SHA1 from the `androiddebugkey` that you will need to add as part of the Android Client ID in the Google console. Then, give it a package name. Use the same package name in your mobile app configuration.

This is what worked for me.